# Limit em Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estou com a seguinte `Query` em Laravel 7.

```
$itens_carros_melhores_ofertas = Veiculo::where('status', 1)
           ->orderBy('ano', 'DESC')
           ->limit(6,9)
           ->get();
```

O problema: preciso exibir os próximos registros, excluindo os **3 primeiros** for buscar. Penso que: `3,9`, buscaria os 6 próximos registros, *mas não é assim o comportamento dele*, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Motivo de negativar?

Comment: Bom não foi que negativei, você quer pegar o que da tabela?

Comment: novic Obg, então. Eu tenho 9 registros. Na minha primeira query, eu tenho 0,3. Eu preciso buscar +6 registros, fora estes 3. No caso, 3,9, acho eu.

Comment: Não poderia usar o `skip(3)`, já que quer ignorar os 3 primeiros?

Comment: Não sei amigo @Woss, sou novo em Laravel (uns 30 dias que estou usando), usei 5 anos CodeIgniter.

Comment: qual a versão do Laravel? é 3,9 mesmo ou talvez 4,9 depende do banco

Comment: novic woss: Resolvi com skip(3), mas a versão que estou usando do Laravel é a 7.3

Comment: Excluo a questão, ou podem incluir uma resposta para ficar para os demais? Agradeço aos dois.

Comment: Não exclua a Questão, veja as respostas e siga em frente, melhorando mais os seus questionamentos

Comment: Ok, agradeço muito @novic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação na parte [Limit & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset) possui duas formas de fazer essa busca de partes de registros começando de um posição:

Exemplo:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

ou

```
users = DB::table('users')->offset(10)->limit(5)->get();
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset</sup>

no seu caso pode fazer assim:

```
$itens_carros_melhores_ofertas = Veiculo::where('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('ano', 'DESC')
    ->offset(3)
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
```